# Reflate old Android Eclipse Project to Android Studio, but Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, installation, manifest

some people had the same failure but their solution don't solves my problem. I get this failure:

*pkg: /data/local/tmp/ich.gamebank

Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]*

Android Studio asks that it can help if it uninstall the existing application but it fails, too:

*DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm uninstall ich.gamebank

DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR*

By the way, this application isn't installed yet.

This ist my AndroidManifest.xml file, the package names has no capital letters.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ich.gamebank"
    android:versionCode="12"
    android:versionName="1.5" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="ich.gamebank.GameBank"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ich.gamebank.SpielerEinstellung"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_spieler_einstellung" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ich.gamebank.SpielerAuswahlEinstellungen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_spieler_auswahl_einstellungen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ich.gamebank.AuswahlBank"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_auswahl_bank" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ich.gamebank.Bezahlen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_bezahlen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ich.gamebank.Kontostand"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_kontostand" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ich.gamebank.SpeicherpunktVerwaltung"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_speicherpunkt_verwaltung" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity" />
        <!-- <activity
           android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" /> -->

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" />

        <activity
            android:name="ich.gamebank.GraphMenu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_graph_menu" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I hope someone can help, thx.

edit: I don't know why but the **problem seems to be solved** when I delete this lines:

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" />
```

I left this thread, if someone had the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> edit: I don't know why but the problem seems to be solved when I delete this lines:
>
> ```
> <meta-data
>     android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" />
> ```
>
> I left this thread, if someone had the same problem.

That's because a `meta-data` element requires both `android:name` and one of `android:value` or `android:resource` attributes. Missing a required attribute flags the manifest as malformed.